# GraphQL Schema Caching or Optimization Ideas

Tags: optimization, caching, graphql

GraphQLSchema object will be used to process graphQL request. This object can be generated once and could be reused multiple times until any meta changes occurs. But my question is how can I cache this object directly in my JVM, since its size is huge (around 17MB ). According to my application, I need to create different schema for different users. Is there any work around for cache the object? Or any optimisation techniques?

[GraphQL Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py1nW.png)

String interning technique can be used to reduce String object size a bit. But this has to be done from their end. Looking for any other quick solutions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.